# divide the bibliography into sections

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I want to divide the references into two sections : bibliography and webography like this :

[image] [image]

This is my code

- biblio.bib

```
@article{pastor2020,
  title={The not yet exploited goldmine of OSINT: Opportunities, open challenges and future trends},
  author={Pastor-Galindo, Javier and Nespoli, Pantaleone and M{\'a}rmol, F{\'e}lix G{\'o}mez and P{\'e}rez, Gregorio Mart{\'\i}nez},
  journal={IEEE Access},
  volume={8},
  pages={10282--10304},
  year={2020},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{vats2020comprehensive,
  title={A Comprehensive Literature Review of Penetration Testing \& Its Applications},
  author={Vats, Prashant and Mandot, Manju and Gosain, Anjana},
  booktitle={2020 8th International Conference on Reliability, Infocom Technologies and Optimization (Trends and Future Directions)(ICRITO)},
  pages={674--680},
  year={2020},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   WEBOGRAPHY    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

@online{breach_cost,
    title = {Cost of a Data Breach Report 2021 {\textbar} {IBM}},
    url = {https://www.ibm.com/security/data-breach},
    urldate = {2021-10-08},
    file = {Cost of a Data Breach Report 2021 | IBM:C\:\\Users\\moutachouiq\\Zotero\\storage\\6EM8SRPC\\data-breach.html:text/html},
}
@online{ec-c0uncil_cehv8_nodate,
    title = {Cehv8 Module 01 : Introduction To Ethical Hacking},
    url = {https://idoc.pub/documents/cehv8-module-01-introduction-to-ethical-hackingpdf-gen5g560x54o},
    abstract = {Cehv8 Module 01 Introduction To Ethical Hacking.pdf [gen5g560x54o]. ...},
    author = {{EC}-C0UNCIL},
    urldate = {2021-10-06},
    langid = {english},
    file = {Snapshot:C\:\\Users\\moutachouiq\\Zotero\\storage\\FA9TUFUT\\cehv8-module-01-introduction-to-ethical-hackingpdf-gen5g560x54o.html:text/html},
}
```

and the main file contains these lines:

```
\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Références}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt-fr}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you considered to use biblatex?